# Form keeps selecting multiple radio buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, radio-button

I have a feeling there is a simple solution to this problem but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm using a mix of jQuery, PHP and HTML to generate this dynamic form of mine.
Each result SQL finds will be passed into the form, it will display a person along with a radio button. So if there are 3 returned results in the DB, the form will generate 3 people and one of them will have the radio button already checked. My problem is, I only want to be able to select 1 of the 3 radio buttons generated. It keeps multi selecting and I don't know what's causing it or how to stop/fix it.
Example:

**Note - showing snipet to illustrate my point**

```
    <?php
    $group_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE gp_ID = '26'")
            or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));  
    ?>
    <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <?php
    $counter = 1;
    $passenger_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM Customers AS C
                        WHERE C.gp_ID = '".$group_Results['gp_ID']."'")
                            or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));  
    while($passenger_Results = mysqli_fetch_array($passenger_query)){
    ?>
    <input type="radio" 
        class="the_Leader" 
        name="the_Leader_<?php echo $counter; ?>"
        value="<?php echo $passenger_Results['customer_ID'] ?>" 
        <?php echo $passenger_Results['customer_ID'] == $group_Results['leader_ID'] ? 'checked' : ''; ?> 
    />
    <?php
        echo $passenger_Results['name'];
        $counter++;
    }//end while loop

    ?>
    </form>
```

**tl;dr dynamic form generated using PHP/MySQL, one of the results is already checked. Want to be able to change it but form multi selects radio buttons.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning different `name=` attributes to the buttons when you write `name="the_Leader_<?php echo $counter; ?>"`.  To be in a button group, all buttons must have the same name.

You want the names to be the same and the *values* to be different; the latter lets you know which button was clicked when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I knew it was something as simple as that. Feeling like the biggest idiot right now haha! Thank you again!